# Building a web service to be consumed by multiple platforms - what format should i use?

Tags: java, php, .net, web-services, node.js

we are looking to create a web service to provide functionality for stateless data transactions on a single data store.  the service will be consumed by applications running several potential environments - at least windows .net, php, and java, but possibly more.

what is the best format to use for passing data back and forth?  "best" i would consider to be the format in the sweet spot between ease of consumption and strongly typed content.  at one end, SOAP tells you everything you need to know about the service but requires a good deal of processing on the client side to parse.  On the other side would be JSON for its minimalist format and ease in parsing, but obviously the client needs to have a very good idea about what data it should be expecting.

would one of these solutions be more ideal than the other?  is there another format to consider?

as a follow up, what frameworks can you recommend to implement the format on the server side?  our server OS is linux, so php or java would be the preferred solution, but an alternate platform like node.js could also be considered.  something like WCF in the .NET world would be ideal since you can write the business logic once and let the presentation framework make it available in several formats simultaneously.

Comment: why do you have to use a linux server?  hosting is cheap.  Dont base a solution on the OS of the server you have.

Comment: our client is a linux shop.  this project is just part of a larger solution that is already running 50+ linux servers.  the IT staff doesn't want to maintain one windows server in the mix.

Comment: point taken on the linux thing... mono really isnt an option as the WCF part is very immature.  Well I am a .net guy by day, and PHP at night.  A PHP solution would not be hard to hack out for REST.

Answer (score 3):

As @WhiteFang34 recommended, REST is a very accessible protocol to you. Even though it is not a standard, it is widely used and well documented in most modern programming languages.

REST merely defines what each HTTP method should do, but you still need to decide what format to use. JSON and XML are the most popular ones, but from my experience [JSON](http://json.org) is a lot less troublesome to work with in most cases.

Comment: JSON is good only if you have small amounts of data.  XML can be wordy but data serializes much nicer.

Comment: @CrazyDart, can you please elaborate?  I've worked with massive JSON files that were readily and accurately unserialized and convoluted XML ones that were brutal to parse.  Choosing a serialization format should ultimately be determined by the data and by the use cases.

Comment: Thanks, juan.  I'm very familiar with REST, and the options of JSON, and XML.   My question is what format would people *recommend* for  data serialization for consumption on multiple platforms, and why.

Comment: @jaminto would you mind elaborating a bit more? Do you mean, how best to represent your objects in, say, JSON? Or is there something additional that I may be missing?

Comment: To illustrate my point take a byte array thats 10,000 long and serialize it with both.  JSON is twice the size as XML.  I know JSON is easy, but you only have to write the de-serialization once and you get the benefit forever.  That said... for small things JSON is smaller.  It all depends on the data.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the WCF REST 4.0 template you can get a REST and SOAP endpoint on the same service.  Its easy as pie.  I think that RESTful is the best way to go for most things.

The nice thing about REST is that its easy to consume.  It can be a bit more work to consume, but it works very cleanly.  SOAP is harder to consume, but once you get it wired up most frameworks work great with it.  Myself, I have never had much luck with using SOAP services across many platforms.

Comment: @JuanD pointed out that you need to know the serialization for REST... and this really depends on the implementation... the WCF REST 4.0 template will return the object in the form it was requested... if you send a content type of XML or JSON it will return a like typed object.

Comment: again, WCF is what i would (and have) used for a windows-based environment, but as the question states, we need something that runs on linux.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer). It's popular for web services. I recommend reading [A Brief Introduction to REST](http://www.infoq.com/articles/rest-introduction) that goes over application-to-application communication with REST. There's also [RESTful Web services: The basics](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restful/). There are plenty of REST solutions to choose for with Java:

1. [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/)
2. [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/)
3. [RESTEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy)
4. [Restlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restlet)
5. [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) ([docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html))

There's also the [JAX-RS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAX-RS) API that most of them adhere to (all of these except Spring).